# Multiple condition in IF in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Take the following statement:

```
SELECT SUM( IF( talktime > 4 AND status = 'answer' , 1, 0 ) ) as count FROM table
```

The output should be count the rows that fulfill both conditions.

Is the statement valid?

EDIT:

I'm interested in the multiple condition part in IF.

Comment: Yes it is valid. You can execute it and see by yourself!

Comment: This comment and answer are highly ironic.  The query will *not* run as written.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: The names `count` and `table` are just for the example :) but I will leave them like that because you made good points. I was interested in the multiple condition part

Comment: @alex . . . We can only answer the questions as they are asked.  Your question clearly has a table named `table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement:

```
SELECT SUM( IF( talktime > 4 AND status = 'answer' , 1, 0 ) ) as count
FROM table
```

is kind of correct, with caveats:

- `table` is not allowed as a table name, because it is a reserved word.  It needs to be escaped.
- `count` is a poor choice for a column name, because it is a built-in function name

You can also simplify the query because the `if()` is not needed in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(talktime > 4 AND status = 'answer') as cnt
FROM `table`;
```

Of course, you can move the comparison logic to a `WHERE` clause, but this is keeping the same structure as the original query.

Answer (score 2):

> **IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)**
>
> If expr1 is TRUE then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3

So the above code will return `1` when the conditions satisfies otherwise return `0`.
So the count will be the `No. of rows satisfying the condition`.

---

For example,

If you want to display `total no .of calls`,`total no of short calls`,`total no of long calls`(Assuming `talktime` length of call duration ).

```
SELECT SUM( IF( talktime > 4 , 1, 0 ) ) as No_of_Long_Calls,
           SUM( IF( talktime < 4 , 1, 0 ) ) as No_of_Short_Calls,
           COUNT(*) AS Total_Calls
    FROM table_name
    WHERE status = 'answer'
```

---

Yeas It is a valid Select Statement,
100 % it will work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE talktime > 4 AND status = 'answer'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) count FROM table WHERE talktime > 4 AND status = 'answer';
```

I really don't realize why you would do this in any other way, but yes, your code should work fine.